# Stop pytest on errors but not on fails

Tags: python, pytest

Pytest reports `error`if an assert fails in an initialization fixture, and `fail`if a test fails after the initialization fixture has run.

To make the test suite stop on errors or failures, the following flags can be used:

`-x, --exitfirst       exit instantly on first error or failed test.`

How can I make the test suite stop after the first error but keep going if there are failures?

Comment: did you try pytest_internalerror hook?

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be hard to implement yourself. A minimal example (untested):

```
# conftest.py

from _pytest.main import Failed


def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    if report.failed and report.when in ('setup', 'teardown'):
        raise Failed()
```

This will continue on test failures (`report.failed and report.when == 'call'`), but stop on setup/teardown errors.

Comment: Calling "Failed()" in the first test in a suite does not seem to stop the other tests from being run though.

Comment: pytest.exit() does the job however!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing all `assert`'s with `pytest.exit("some_message")` in the initialization fixture does the trick.